# expo FCM Notification

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have enabled notifications through FCM notifications feature in my Expo React Native application. However, I noticed that when the app is open or in the foreground, the notifications appear as alerts. Is there a way to display them in the standard notification format instead?

```
 const requestUserPermission = async () => {
    const authStatus = await messaging().requestPermission();
    const enabled =
      authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.AUTHORIZED ||
      authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.PROVISIONAL;

    if (enabled) {
      console.log("Authorization status:", authStatus);
    }
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    if (requestUserPermission()) {
      messaging()
        .getToken()
        .then((token) => AsyncStorage.setItem("expotoken", token));
    } else {
      console.log("Falid Token statues", authStatus);
    }
    messaging()
      .getInitialNotification()
      .then(async (remoteMessage) => {
        if (remoteMessage) {
          console.log(
            "Notification caused app to open from quit state:",
            remoteMessage.notification
          );
        }
      });
    messaging().onNotificationOpenedApp(async (remoteMessage) => {
      console.log(
        "Notification caused app to open from background state:",
        remoteMessage.notification
      );
    });
    messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async (remoteMessage) => {
      console.log("Message handled in the background!", remoteMessage);
    });
    const unsubscribe = messaging().onMessage(async (remoteMessage) => {
      Alert.alert("A new FCM message arrived!", JSON.stringify(remoteMessage));
      // onDisplayNotification()
    });
    return unsubscribe;
   
  }, []);
```

I tried notifee but I can't use it in Expo.